# Find values of a and b for different dim(V).

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, gaussian-elimination

Given the solution space V,

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x_1+2x_2-x_3-5x_4=0 \\ 
-x_1+3x_3+5x_4=0 \\ 
x_1+x_2+ax_3+bx_4=0
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

By applying Gaussian Jordan Elimination, I get from
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
  1&2&-1&-5&0\\
  -1&0&3&5&0\\
1&1&a&b&0
\end{array}
\right] $$

to 
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
  1&0&-3&-5&0\\
  0&1&1&0&0\\
0&0&a+2&b+5&0
\end{array}
\right] $$
If dim(V) = 2, I can assume that a+2 = 0 and b+5 = 0, to give 2 pivot columns, hence a = -2 and b = -5.

However, if dim(V) = 1, how do I go about solving for a and b, as I can't seem to find a way to further reduce the above matrix?
Also, is it possible if dim(V) take on other values e.g. 0 and 3?

Comment: Hint: if Dim(V) = 1 you have only one free variable.

Comment: Hint: How many nonzero rows do you get if $a\ne-2$ or $b\ne-5$?

Comment: If a≠−2  or b≠−5, there would be 3 nonzero rows, so how would you derive at Dim(V) = 1?

Answer (score 1):

The dimension of the column space and the dimension of the row space of a matrix are always the same. Since the first two columns are independent from each other, the column space will always have dimension at least 2, and since there are only 3 rows, the row space can have dimension at most 3. Thus we can say the rank is at least 2 and at most 3.